# Android white background EditText that act as button

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

[image]

I'm trying to Style an EditText to look like the one in the above picture.
I tried setting a background but the result was not at all as excpected

Could you someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: all you need is a proper `android:background`

Comment: I have tried setting it as @null so that the EditText line would disappear but then I have no idea how to have the button looks like its elevated.

Comment: looking closer on the shadows it seems that it is a `CardView` + `EditText`

Comment: https://letustech.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/customedittext/

Comment: @pskink it was totally a card view + edit text inside... !

Comment: nice to hear my guess was right...

Answer (score 3):

use this xml as background fro your `edittext`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and put some padding in your `edittext`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android CardView Library and set EditText background to null
Below is the sample code for it

Add the library in gradle for cardview 
 **compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- Card Contents go here -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_first_name"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:editable="true"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:text="Text"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            ></ImageView>


                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```